# Terraform: Create an Azure Policy Initiative with multiple custom Azure Policies with Parameters

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

I want to create an Azure Policy Initiative with multiple custom Azure Policies

I have the following custom policy

```
# Azure Provider source and version being used
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
        source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = "~> 3.30.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

// Policy Category
variable "policy_definition_category" {
  type        = string
  description = "The category to use for all PolicySet defintions"
  default     = "Custom"
}   

// Policy Definition for Role Audit
resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "auditRoleAssignmentType" {
  name         = "auditRoleAssignmentType"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  mode         = "All"
  display_name = "Audit user role assignments"
  description  = "This policy checks for any Role Assignments of Type [User] - useful to catch individual IAM assignments to resources/RGs which are out of compliance with the RBAC standards e.g. using Groups for RBAC."

  metadata = <<METADATA
    {
    "category": "${var.policy_definition_category}",
    "version" : "1.0.0"
    }
METADATA

  policy_rule = <<POLICY_RULE
    {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/principalType",
          "equals": "[parameters('principalType')]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  }
POLICY_RULE

  parameters = <<PARAMETERS
    {
    "principalType": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "principalType",
        "description": "Which principalType to audit against e.g. 'User'"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "User",
        "Group",
        "ServicePrincipal"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "User"
    }
  }
PARAMETERS

}

// Display the Policy ID
output "auditRoleAssignmentType" {
  value       = "${azurerm_policy_definition.auditRoleAssignmentType.id}"
  description = "The policy definition id for auditRoleAssignmentType"
}
```

I have the following Initiative definition

```
// List of Policy Definitions for the Custom Initiative
variable "list_of_policies_definitions" {
  type        = list
  description = "List of policy definitions"
  default = [
    "auditRoleAssignmentType"
  ]
}

// Get the list of Policies
data "azurerm_policy_definition" "custom_policies_definitions" {
  count        = length(var.list_of_policies_definitions)
  display_name = var.list_of_policies_definitions[count.index]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_policy_definition.auditRoleAssignmentType
  ]
}

// Define parameters for the Custom Initiative
variable "custom_initiative_parameters" {
  type        = list
  description = "List of policy definitions"
  default = [
    <<PARAMETERS
    {
      "principalType": {
        "value": "User"
      }
    }
    PARAMETERS,
    <<PARAMETERS
    {
      "paramfornextpolicy": {
        "value": "valuefornextpolicy"
      }
    }
    PARAMETERS    
  ]
}

// Initiative Category
variable "policyset_definition_category" {
  type        = string
  description = "The category to use for all PolicySet defintions"
  default     = "Custom"
}

// Initiative Definition 
resource "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "custom_initiative" {

  name         = "custom_initiative"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  display_name = "Custom Initiative"
  description  = "Contains common policies"

  metadata = <<METADATA
    {
    "category": "${var.policyset_definition_category}"
    }
METADATA

  dynamic "policy_definition_reference" {
    for_each = data.azurerm_policy_definition.custom_policies_definitions
    content {
      policy_definition_id = policy_definition_reference.value["id"]
      reference_id         = policy_definition_reference.value["id"]
      parameters           = var.custom_initiative_parameters["id"]
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    data.azurerm_policy_definition.custom_policies_definitions
  ]
}
```

I am getting the following error

> │ Error: Unsupported argument │
> │   on main.tf line 151, in resource
> "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "custom_initiative": │
> 151: parameters  = var.custom_initiative_parameters["id"] │
> │ An argument named "parameters" is not expected here.

I understand that "parameter_values" should be used, but I'm not sure how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This I how you [Pass parameter_values](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11327):

You can pass `parameter_values` as shown here:

```bash
PARAMETERS
  policy_definition_reference {
    policy_definition_id = azurerm_policy_definition.test.id
    parameter_values = jsonencode({ //"`jsonencode` -> Converts into json parameter file"
      allowedLocations = { value: "[parameters('allowedLocations')]"}
    })
  }
}
```

*After adding values, I modified & tried to create a custom policy definition to see if the parameter values were being given*.

*It worked for me as expected and added terraform code below:*

***vi main.tf:***

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.35.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "example" {
  name         = "xxxxx"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  mode         = "All"
  display_name = "xxxx"
  policy_rule = <<POLICY_RULE
    {
    "if": {
      "not": {
        "field": "location",
        "in": "[parameters('allowedLocations')]"
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  }
POLICY_RULE
  parameters = <<PARAMETERS
  {
    "allowedLocations": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The list of allowed locations for resources.",
        "displayName": "Allowed locations",
        "strongType": "location"
      }
    }
  }
PARAMETERS
}
resource "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "example" {
  name         = "xxxx-example"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  display_name = "xxxxxx-example"
  parameters = <<PARAMETERS
    {
        "allowedLocations": {
            "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "List of allowed locations.",
                "displayName": "Allowed locations",
                "strongType": "location"
            }
        }
    }
PARAMETERS
  policy_definition_reference {
    policy_definition_id = azurerm_policy_definition.example.id
    parameter_values = jsonencode({
      allowedLocations = { value: "[parameters('allowedLocations')]"}
    })
  }
}
```

`terraform plan`:

[image]

`terraform apply`:

[image]

***Policy definition added in the Portal with parameter values:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The parameter in the azurerm_policy_set_definition has the parameter definition but not the default value. How do I set the default value to eastus?

Comment: Thank you. You can directly provide `"defaultValue": "EastUS"` under parameters section. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-parameters#sample-3-parameterized-effect) added for better understanding.